# Removing a fly out from a site I didn't build (is it embedded in code?)

Tags: wordpress, themes

I work for a company and have taken over responsibility for maintaining the website. The company hired an outside agency to create its website. They used Wordpress and templates. I'm used to coding with things like Divi...I'm not 100% sure how to manipulate their work.

http://comfortcarehomehealth.com.  We have a fly out on the right hand side that says "Contact". It used to house a form that wasn't directing correctly so I deleted the form. However, I have no idea how to delete this little "contact" piece. I've searched within the Wordpress theme customizer and attempted to find it in the editor but I don't really know what I'm looking for. I'm not a coder so...

How do I get rid of the "contact" fly out completely?

I can find it in the view source:

```
<div class="cover" data-img="https://comfortcarehomehealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/CC_Vol2_1440x620_HIRES1.jpg">
<div class="help">
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="button-open">
        <i></i>
        <span>Contact</span>
    </a>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="header">How can we help you?</div>
                        </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Hi. Do you have access to the site's backend through FTP? If so, have you checked all the theme's template files?

Comment: hi Denisey! I just got ftp today. I will check. big eye roll because that didn't occur to me. thank you!